# How to set every item in the array A references to initialValue Java

Tags: java

```
public static void initialize(int A[], int initialValue) { ; }
```

this is the start of my code, asking how you can make it so that after running, every item in the array A becomes what I made initialValue. It's for a school assignment and the professor told us we can't use anything with an arrays function so no arrays.func

Thanks!

Comment: Simple in a single line: `for(int i = 0, l = A.length; i < l; A[i++] = initialValue);`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need that method.

Just call

```
Arrays.fill(A,initialValue);
```

BTW, your title has a mistake. Your array is a primitive array, so it won't contain references to `initialValue`, it will contain that `int` value multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

This can be an another solution,

```
/*
 * initialize a smaller piece of the array and use the System.arraycopy 
 * call to fill in the rest of the array in an expanding binary fashion
 */
public static void initialize(int A[], int initialValue) { 

    int len = A.length;

    if (len > 0){
        A[0] = initialValue;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i += i) {
       System.arraycopy(A, 0, A, i, ((len - i) < i) ? (len - i) : i);
    }

}

public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    int A[] = new int[5];
    initialize(A,1);
    for (int i : A) {
        System.out.println(A[i]);
    } 
}
```

OUTPUT:
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: because *initialize a smaller piece of the array and use the System.arraycopy* sounds like a bad idea to me: it seems *how to complicate simple things*

Comment: @fantaghirocco, but compared to Arrays.fill this way is much faster in case of large arrays and OP asked to code in his existing method that is y I have given that answer, and also could you provide me more explanation, why you feel it is a bad idea?

Comment: compared to this `for (int i=0; i<A.length; ++i) A[i] = initialValue;` your solution seems overcomplicated to me sir

Comment: @fantaghirocco, thanks for the clarification, no problem :).